# Running two scripts using the subprocess library in VSCode

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, subprocess

I have two independent scripts that need to be run all the time and display messages in the terminal: script1.py and script2

To run the scripts I use the code editor VSCode under Windows. In order to use the 2 independent terminals I create them separately and in each of them I write the command: python script1.py and python script2.py

Each time I restart, I have to do it all over again. (yes it's not hard, but I think there is a way that could run both scripts and create separate terminals in VSCode)

What I tried to do:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["python", "script1.py"], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
subprocess.Popen(["python", "script2.py"], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

This execution option brings up two separate command-line interpreter windows. This is the usual сmd.exe so if I didn't use VSCode but ran the scripts directly through the Windows console.

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script1.py"], shell=True)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script2.py"], shell=True)
```

This execution option outputs the result of 2 scripts into one VSCode terminal, which is inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the solution to the problem itself has been written in your question:

> In order to use the 2 independent terminals I create them separately
> and in each of them I write the command: python script1.py and python
> script2.py

This is the most correct and safe method. Of course, if you feel troublesome, I can provide the following alternatives:

1. Install [code-runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, then use **Run Code** button (default shortcuts "Ctrl+Alt+N") to run the `python1.py` then **Run Python file** (default shortcuts "Shift+Enter") button to run the `python2.py`.

[image]

2. Use jupyter-notebook, and create the same codes in `python1.ipynb` and `python2.ipynb`. Run the codes in interactive windows is a good choice aswell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I chose option 1, the only thing I did was in the settings of the code-runner extension check the Run in the terminal